# How to add run in paragraph using python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I want to put runs in one paragraph to another using , so I write code like this:
But it does not work.
How should I change this code?

```
from docx import Document                                                                                                                        from docxcompose.composer import Composer                                                                                                      
import re                                                                                                                                      
import time                                                                                                                                    
import os                         

master = Document("out.docx")
po = master.add_paragraph('It is: ')
doc = Document("in4.docx")                                                                                                                   
   for p in doc.paragraphs:                                                                                                                     
       if re.search('yyy', p.text):                                                                                                               
           for r in p.runs:                                                                                                                       
               master.paragraphs[-1].runs.append(r)

master.save('out1.doc1')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

For each matching run, you can create a new run with text and style from the source into the destination Document.

```python
from docx import Document
import re                                                                                                                                      
import time                                                                                                                                    
import os                         

master = Document()
po = master.add_paragraph('It is: ')
doc = Document("demo1.docx")
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    if re.search('yyy', p.text):
        for r in p.runs:
            po.add_run(text=r.text, style=r.style)

master.save('out1.docx')
```

If you're not searching for a regular expression then instead do a text search:

```
if 'yyy' in p.text: ...
```